# Plus sign in query parameter becomes empty string (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my application I want to add sorting like that: 'https://example.com/entity?sort_by=+property'.

When I try to pass plus sign to query, ASP.NET Core returns 'property' without plus sign.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Unless you intend for `+` to mean `" "`, then you should encode your string.

Answer (score 4):

The plus symbol is a reserved character according [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) which is the standard specification for URIs and it is used to represent a space, therefore, if you want to use it in your URL as literally the "+" character instead of a space, you need to encode it so it looks like:

https://example.com/entity?sort_by=%2Bproperty

In ASP.NET Core you can encode / decode URL's as follows:

```
using System.Net;

string url = "https://example.com/entity?sort_by=+property";

string encodedUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(url);
string decodedUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(encodedUrl);
```

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for more info about URL encoding.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into encoding issues with plus signs in url parameters and the fix for us was to use the following.

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(urlParameter);
Uri.UnescapeDataString(escapedUrlParameter);
```

Wanted to share this in case anyone else runs into the same issue.